# Dropdown menu with rounded corners in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, menu, dropdown, rounded-corners

I've found out that if I modify the class **_DropdownMenuPainter** inside *material/dropdown.dart* and change *BorderRadius.circular(2.0)* to *BorderRadius.circular(24.0)*, I get my desired outcome, as I want to have rounded corners on my DropdownButton menu.

However I don't think it's a good practice, since the change would not be inside my project. How can I have this modification in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `borderRadius` properties in `DropdownButton` should do the trick.

```
DropdownButton(
 borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(10),
 child: ...
)
```

Comment: DropdownButton borderRadius property was added on flutter 2.5. Beforehand I had to override the entire class on my app. I was using import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide DropdownButton, DropdownButtonFormField, DropdownButtonHideUnderline, DropdownMenuItem;